# How do I convert a google spreadsheet key from long key to short key or vice versa

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In my Apps Script application I am trying to compare spreadsheet keys with each other.

Sometimes I get a long key (0AsJuL0r...) and sometimes I get a short key (tBKGg0dQ...) and they both reference the same spreadsheet but are not the same and so my comparison fails.

If I knew how to convert from long to short (or short to long) then I could run the conversion and then compare in order to check the keys are the same.

The only thing I've tried so far is using base64 encoding/decoding but that didn't seem to work.

How can I convert these keys so they are comparable? Failing that, how can I get a unique unchanging reference to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant convert them without calling an api. SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getId will always give you the short one so you can do that to normalize your ids.
The root problem seems to be that you use different methods to get a ids (from the spreadsheet url you get the long one). You should always convert to short id before storing it.

Comment: Which API do I need to call to convert them? I took a look in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ But couldn't see it.

Comment: Can't you read?  It's clearly written in the above answer:  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getId

Comment: No need to be so agressive, of course I can read. I just didn't understand the terminology used; when Zig said API i thought he meant an API like the one I linked to. I've now re-read the answer and understand properly.

Comment: Sorry, It was not my intention to be aggressive but I realize it was a bit rude. Please accept my apologizes.